# Ok, my @yield or @extends is not working because some reason

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I just wanna print something thanks to `@yield` in my layout (cristarium), but for some reason is doing nothing, it just appear the text `MASTER` but don't `HELLO`.

**VIEWS FOLDER LOCATIONS**

> resources\views\ffxiii-2\cristarium.blade.php

> resources\views\ffxiii-2\cristarium_personajes\noel_kreiss.blade.php

**ROUTE IN WEB.PHP**

```
Route::get('/ffxiii-2/cristarium', function () {
    return view('ffxiii-2.cristarium');
})->name('cristarium');
```

**LAYOUT -> cristarium.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Cristarium</title>
</head>

<body>
    MASTER
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**BLADE TO PRINT -> noel_kreiss.blade.php**

```
@extends('ffxiii-2.cristarium')

@section('content')
    HELLO
@endsection
```

I tried to change the name's folder avoiding the underscore, and changing to the - in ffxiii-2, but still don't work, so I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views cascade the other way.

Your route is showing the view which renders the file `ffxiii/cristarium.blade.php`,
this is your master layout.

What you need to do is to return the view `ffxiii-2/cristarium_personajes/noel_kreiss` from the route, which will the render that view, which in turn includes your master layout.

E.g.

```
Route::get('/ffxiii-2/cristarium', function () {
    return view('ffxiii-2.cristarium_personajes.noel_kreiss');
})->name('noel_kreiss');
```

Comment: Thanks m8, thats the theory I need it to understand hehehe.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the `layout` file in your controller method. But I think you should return the second file (noel_kreiss.blade.php):

```
Route::get('/ffxiii-2/cristarium', function () {
    return view('ffxiii-2.cristarium_personajes.noel_kreiss');
})->name('cristarium');
```